# jScrollPane autoReinitialise and animateScroll

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have a jScrollpane (jQuery) problem

I use jScrollpane on my website. I have dynamic content that makes the scroll-area larger. This makes the attribute autoReinitialise mandatory.
I also want to use the animateScroll attribute, but if I use those at the same time, the scrollbar wil go mad (mad i tell you!).

Does someone know what's up with that?

http://www.bidadari.nl/?page_id=98

```
var pane = jQuery("#scroll_area");
pane.jScrollPane({
    autoReinitialise: true,
    showArrows: true,
    verticalArrowPositions: "split",
    horizontalArrowPositions: "split",
    animateScroll: true
});
var api = pane.data("jsp");
jQuery("#button_step_right").bind("click", function() {
    api.scrollByX(750);
    return false;       
});
```

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah. The correct answer was:

```
var pane = jQuery("#scroll_area");
pane.jScrollPane({
   autoReinitialise: true,
   showArrows: true,
   verticalArrowPositions: "split",
   horizontalArrowPositions: "split",
  /// animateScroll: true
});
   var api = pane.data("jsp");
   jQuery("#button_step_right").bind("click", function() {
   api.scrollByX(750, true); /// <- true
   return false;       
});
```